# Finding distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, random-variables

For the following, determine the distribution that the random variable $X$ follows (be sure to include appropriate parameters):

1. A particle starts at $(0, 0)$ and moves in one-unit steps that are independent and with probabilities in two directions: a probability of $0.5$ going North and $0.5$ going West. $X$ is the $x$ coordinate after $3$ steps.
2. A country club has $4$ halls: halls $A, B$, $C$ and $D$. Each hall has $25$ tables for a total of $50$ guests. Let $X$ be the number of tables in hall $A$ that are occupied after the first $18$ guests arrive. Guests arrive at the club at random, each order equally likely.
3. There are two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that they have a joint distribution given by

$$f(x, y)= \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr} 
      \frac{1}{e^y} & \mbox{if } x \in [0, \infty), y \in [x, \infty) \\
      0 & \mbox{otherwise} 
      \end{array}
\right.$$

My attempt:

1. $X$ has a binomial distribution with $n = 3$ and $p = 0.5$.
2. I think is either exponential with $\theta = 25$ or gamma with $\theta = 25$ and $\alpha = 18$.
3. $X$ has a marginal distribution?

Are my solutions correct? If not, what is/are the correct distributions? Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think

1. $X\sim B(3,0.5)$
2. $X\sim B(18,1/4)$  (we have 18 trials / persons, each person with 1/4 prob. goes to room A, $X$ is total number of persons in room A - you can verify with simulation)
3. $X$ has marginal distribution (integrate $y$ out): $f(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy=e^{-x}$

Comment: For #2, where would the number of tables come in?

Comment: @Kraftsman, For #2 ... the question should give more detail on how guests are assigned to the two seats at each of the 25 tables in a hall.  Sandipan's answer presumes that guests are assigned halls at random, but then each sits at an *empty* table.

Comment: @GrahamKemp What seats? The question doesn't mention any seats...

Comment: 25 tables for a total of 50 guests...  @Kraftsman

Comment: @GrahamKemp Suppose instead that it was $2$ halls: $A$ and $B$ instead of $4$. Everything kept the same, would this be more detailed?